# boost asio - check if ip is from a particular subnet

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I have to check if an IP address belongs to a predefined subnet. For example, IP Address 192.168.0.1 is in CIDR range 192.168.0.0/24.

I've tried with:

- https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__network_v4.html
- https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__address_v4.html

There is a method:

`is_subnet_of` for `network_v4` class, but nothing similar for `adress_v4`. Did I miss something?

Comment: Most methods regarding subnets in `ip::address_v4` are deprecated so probably you have to use `ip::network_v4`.

Comment: @ThomasSablik so how can I handle this task with network_v4?

Comment: You can create a `ip::network_v4` with [ip::network_v4::network_v4](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__network_v4/network_v4/overload2.html) and compare the [network](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__network_v4/network.html)

Comment: @ThomasSablik something like this:

`network_v4 addr = make_network_v4("192.168.0.1/32");
network_v4 net = make_network_v4("192.168.0.0/24");
cout << addr.is_subnet_of(net) << endl;`

So basically - threat an IP address as subnet with mask 32? It does not look like an elegant solution.

Comment: No, I meant `network_v4 addr = make_network_v4("192.168.0.1/24"); addr.network == address_v4("192.168.0.0/24");`

Comment: Ok. So If I want to check if an IP Address 192.168.0.1 belongs to a subnet 192.168.0.0/24, I have to append the same CIDR (24) to the 192.168.0.1 and compare networks?

Comment: Each subnet has a network address and a broadcast address. With CIDR you can calculate the corresponding subnet to an IP address and `network` will return you the network address.

Answer (score 7):

```cpp
    using namespace boost::asio;
    // make a subnet with 255.255.255.0
    ip::network_v4 subnet = ip::make_network_v4("192.168.0.0/24");
    // get all the hosts from this subnet
    ip::address_v4_range hosts = subnet.hosts();

    boost::system::error_code error_code;
    // create target address
    ip::address addr = ip::make_address("192.168.0.1", error_code);
    if (error_code)
    {
        throw std::invalid_argument(error_code.message());
    }

    // Now check if the address is one of the hosts in the subnet
    if(hosts.find(addr.to_v4()) != hosts.end()) {
        std::cout << "yes" << std::endl;
    }
```

Comment: You should explain why this is a solution to the original question. It doesn't seem so...

Comment: If i understand right the OP want to check if 192.168.0.1 is belongs to 192.168.0.0/24? You get the answer, it is

Comment: Again, you need to ***explain*** what you have done in your answer!

Comment: OK, I see... it's a small piece of code, I thought anyone has a little knowledge of C++ should understand it with no problem. But no, I was wrong :). I should put some comment

Comment: This solution does not work as expected.
In your solution "1.2.3.4" does not match the network "1.2.3.4/30". But it is expected to match))

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a network object which is composed of an IP and a prefix length (= Subnet). Note that the IP might be, but doesn't need to be the network IP. The network IP is called canonical within Asio's network classes. (The network IP is the first IP within your Subnet. E.g. `192.168.13.15/24` has the canonical IP `192.168.13.0`.)

Then you create a second network from your test IP with the same prefix length as your reference network and compare the canonical IPs of the Networks. (You could compare the canonical networks directly, but this includes the prefix lengths from which we know they are equal. A bit less code, but also a bit less efficient.)

```cpp
#include <asio.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

namespace ip = asio::ip;

bool contains(ip::network_v4 const& network, ip::address_v4 const& ip){
    return network.canonical().address() ==
        ip::network_v4(ip, network.prefix_length()).canonical().address();
}

int main(){
    auto const make = [](auto const v){ return ip::make_address_v4(v); };
    std::cout << std::boolalpha
        << contains({make("192.168.0.5"), 24}, {make("192.168.0.200")}) << "\n"
        << contains({make("192.168.0.5"), 24}, {make("192.168.0.6")}) << "\n"
        << contains({make("192.192.0.5"), 24}, {make("192.168.0.200")}) << "\n"
        << contains({make("192.192.0.5"), 24}, {make("192.168.0.6")}) << "\n"
        << contains({make("192.168.0.5"), 30}, {make("192.168.0.200")}) << "\n"
        << contains({make("192.168.0.5"), 30}, {make("192.168.0.6")}) << "\n";
}
```

*Note 1:* You can replace `make` by `ip::make_address_v4`. Its just a short cut to make a nice code format alignment here.

*Note 2:* If you use Boost.Asio instead of freestanding Asio, just replace `<asio.hpp>` by `<boost/asio.hpp>` and `ip = asio::ip` by `ip = boost::asio::ip`.

Output:

```
true
true
false
false
false
true
```

I opened an Issue to add a `contains` method to the network classes:

- https://github.com/chriskohlhoff/asio/issues/952